# How can i type ª in a 80% keyboad (without a numpad)

Tags: windows, keyboard, characters

Is there a way that i can type the feminine ordinal indicator on a keyboard without a numpad?

Comment: a lot of those keyboards are programmable, could you possibly abuse that in some way?

Comment: You could use [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ref:**

1. [Unicode input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input)
2. [Insert ASCII or Unicode Latin-based symbols and characters](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-ascii-or-unicode-latin-based-symbols-and-characters-d13f58d3-7bcb-44a7-a4d5-972ee12e50e0)

*Windows:*
Type `U+00aa` then hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and hit <kbd>x</kbd> ⬝⬝⬝⬝▶ `ª`

*Linux:*
Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>, hit <kbd>u</kbd> *(you will see an underlined `u`)*, type `00aa` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> ⬝⬝⬝⬝▶ `ª`
Alternatively:  Keep holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> while typing `u00aa`, release ⬝⬝⬝⬝▶ `ª`
*Also: At least here the `0`:es are optional.*

**More characters?**
Run `Charmap` (Windows) or `Characters` (Linux),
click on a character and look for the "code key"-value.

*Those arrows are 4x u+2b1d and one u+25b6, assuming your browser renders them correctly.*

Comment: The Windows solution isn't Windows-native. It's a feature of some text editors, as noted in the Wikipedia link you've provided. It works for me in Word for example, but not in Notepad or Firefox.

Comment: FWIW I'm creating this using Firefox in Ubuntu GNU/Linux. Notepad might be seen as a simple application with code stemming from very old times (Win 9x), might be; not with a base that is simple to modify for unicode compatibility.

Comment: FWIW Notepad defaults to UTF-8 since Windows 8.1 (IIRC), but that's not my point really. It's just not a global Windows feature. It works only in programs that specifically implement it themselves.

Comment: Well, I believe my point still stands; if it is as you say: the code used to create Notepad doesn't fully implement support for Unicode - if it doesn't allow ENTRY of such characters.

Comment: It _does_ allow entry of such characters, but not using the method you've described. Same with Firefox, Sublime Text, Windows Terminal, Meld, Steam, Excel 2019, Inkscape, Windows search and all the other old and new Windows programs that I didn't test, _with exceptions_. In does work in Word, LibreOffice suite and Wordpad, because these programs apparently implement it themselves. It is not a native, system-wide Windows feature unfortunately. Your source confirms this: _"In some applications (Word, WordPad and LibreOffice programs) a simpler method is supported: [...]"_.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install a free [alternative Windows keyboard layout](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/switch-alternate-keyboard-layouts-windows-10/).
2. Create a [custom Windows keyboard layout](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-desktop/how-to-install-custom-klc-file-for-keyboard-layout/1651871e-cf33-4888-abc9-f7980b3c1cd0).